# In how many 4th permutations of given subset $a$ and $b$ are adjacent?

Tags: permutations

Suppose we are given that

$$K = \{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$$

In how many 4th permutations of given subset $a$ and $b$ are adjacent?

So we have four choices for remaining letters when we put $a$ and $b$

$$ab\_\space \_$$

Now let us pick 2 letters out of 4 letters, which can be done in $\binom{4}{2}$
ways. However, $a$ and $b$ have to be together so we can consider them as an object yielding $3!$ Thereby, we finally have that

$$\binom{4}{2}3! = 6^2 = 36$$

Am I right?

Regards

Comment: Close., I would consider $a$ and $b$ to be adjacent in the string $baef$ as well.  Your answer would be correct if not only $a$ and $b$ needed to be adjacent but also that $a$ must occur before $b$ so you missed counting half of them.

Comment: @JMoravitz Could you be more clear with what you mean?

Comment: Not really... I can try again.  You counted strings like $\overline{ab}cd, \overline{ab}ce, \overline{ab}cf, \overline{ab}dc, \dots, c\overline{ab}d, c\overline{ab}e, c\overline{ab}f,\dots, fe\overline{ab}$.  You should *also* have counted strings like $\overline{ba}cd, \overline{ba}ce, \overline{ba}cf,\dots, fe\overline{ba}$.  The phrase "$a$ and $b$ are adjacent" merely means that $ab$ is a substring **or that ba is a substring**.  You only counted where $a$ occurs to the immediate left of $b$ but you should also have counted where $a$ occurs to the immediate **right** of $b$ as well.

Comment: Your logic and workings are good but ignored that final step of determining whether $a$ is to the left of $b$ or if $a$ is to the right of $b$.  Multiplying the final result by two corrects this.